# Strengthening of the local smoothing estimates for the free Laplacian

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes

The classical local-smoothing estimates for the free Laplacian asserts that:
$$\Vert e^{-it\Delta}f\Vert_{L^2((-\infty,+\infty)\,;\,H^{1/2}(B))}\leq C_B\cdot\Vert f\Vert_{L^2}$$
where $B\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ is a bounded set, and $C_B$ is a constant depending only on $B$ (if $B$ is a ball of radius $R$, one can take $C_B=c\cdot R^{1/2}$, for some absolute constant $c$). In particular, this implies that for almost every time there is a gain of one-half derivative, locally in space.

I also know that a similar estimate fails if we replaced $H^{1/2}$ with $H^{1/2+\varepsilon}$, for some $\varepsilon>0$. However, the estimate could still be true in an appropriate intermediate space (for example some Triebel-Lizorkin space). So my (a bit vague) question is:

**Question:** There exists a Banach space (or a complete quasi-normed space) $X$, included in $H^{1/2}(\mathbb{R}^n)$, which admits natural restrictions $X_B$ to bounded sets, and such that the following "smoothing estimate"
$$\Vert e^{-it\Delta}f\Vert_{L^2((-\infty,+\infty)\,;\,X(B))}\leq C_B\cdot\Vert f\Vert_{L^2}$$
holds true? Thank you for any suggestions.